# Bootstrap material design causing issue with click event of Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having a strange issue with my angular app when I have used bootstrap material design to make app responsive.

The app works just fine in normal website size.

[image: WebsiteView]

But when testing in mobile or in responsive mode of the browser, it looks like this due to material library:

[image: Mobile View]

Problem is the click of all button stops working in responsive mode. When I again resize the view to normal browser size, it again starts working.

**Updated:**
I have reviewed this behavior and found that the click works fine for all buttons in device except the buttons which are moved inside the accordion by library. They stop working.

Comment: Where can we reproduce your issue?

Comment: Ok, that a pretty common problem, we had the same problem with Datatables.
You need to find out when your on mobile and catch the click on the button and disabled the click on the "table".